# How do I search a redis set and return the key if there are more than x members in the set?

Tags: node.js, redis

Using this library: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

Here's an example of my code:

```
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:1");
redisdb.sadd("list:1", "list:1:stuff:abc");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:2");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:3");
redisdb.sadd("list:3", "list:3:stuff:def");
redisdb.sadd("list:3", "list:3:stuff:def");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:4");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:5");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:6");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:7");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:8");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:9");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:10");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:11");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:12");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:13");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:14");
redisdb.sadd("list", "list:15");
```

Let's say I wanted to search the set called `list` and get the key of any set within `list` that has more than x members.

For example, if I'm looking for the key of any set within `list` that has more than 1 member, it would return list:3.

Is this possible? If so, can someone please direct me on how I would go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `ioredis` but the idea is similar.

```
redis.smembers('list')
    .then(function (members) {
        console.log('members', members);

        var pipeline = redis.pipeline()

        members.map(function (key) {
            pipeline.scard(key)    
        })

        return pipeline.exec()
    })
    .then(function (counts) {
        console.log('counts', counts);
    })
```

Output:

```
members [ 'list:12',
  'list:1',
  'list:11',
  'list:8',
  'list:10',
  'list:7',
  'list:3',
  'list:9',
  'list:15',
  'list:5',
  'list:14',
  'list:2',
  'list:13',
  'list:6',
  'list:4' ]
counts [ [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 1 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 1 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ],
  [ null, 0 ] ]
```

Or if you want to do it your way: stop as soon as it finds a non-empty list

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
var Promise = require('bluebird');

redis.smembers('list')
    .then(function (members) {
        console.log('members', members);

        var allPromises = members.map(function (key) {
            return getMemberCount(key)
        })

        return Promise.any(allPromises)
    })
    .then(function (listName) {
        console.log('found', listName);
    })

function getMemberCount(key) {
    return redis.scard(key)
        .then(function (cnt) {
            if (cnt === 0) throw new Error('empty set')
            else return key
        })   
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to limit it so that it returns the first key that it finds that meets the criteria and then stops? thanks!

Comment: Because I use pipeline to search all at once and get back to me. However, if you want to do it your way, you can pass an array of Promises (scard operation, throw if 0) to bluebird `Promise.any` and it will stop as soon as it find a list with 1 element.